# how to upload files to a shared protected storage link using curl?

Tags: curl, qnap

I want to upload files to a shared link (Qnap storage link) using cURL, how can I do this if i have just a password for the shared link , I do not have a username or an account.
I have tried

```
$ curl -u 'password' --upload-file file.txt  https://MY_LINK_DIR/file.txt
```

but it seems , that is not the right way to do this.
can anyone help?

Comment: The default username is "admin" so you could try `curl -u 'admin:password' ...` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try (thanks [icarus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/194382/icarus)):

```
 curl -u 'admin:password' [...]
```

See https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/faq/article/what-are-the-default-administrator-username-and-password-in-qts